# Coq: freeing universes

Tags: coq

Is there a way to `Reset` (or more generally, free) universes in Coq?

```
Universe M.
Print Sorted Universes. (*M = Type.2*)
Fail Print M. (*Error: M not a defined object.*)
Reset M.
Print Sorted Universes. (*M = Type.2*)
Definition M := Type@{M}.
Print M. (*M = Type: Type*)
Print Sorted Universes. (*M = Type.2*)
Reset M.
Fail Print M. (*Error: M not a defined object.*)
Print Sorted Universes. (*M = Type.2*)
```

Whatever I do, `M = Type.2`. I'm in Coq 8.5

Comment: I'm afraid I am not familiar with 8.5 codebase to know what is possible there, 8.6 has a new implementation of universe checking so YMMV.

Comment: @ejgallego: Does `Universe M. Reset M.` clear the universe in 8.6?

Comment: I don't know, but it outputs the warning: `Reset not implemented for automatically generated constants`

Comment: All that I can say is that `Reset` is not something designed to be relied upon an actual script. As Arthur, I wonder what the use case is here.

Comment: @ejgallego: A use case would be redefining universes' `Constraint`s. What should actual scripts rely on instead of `Reset` in freeing variables? `Local`, `Section`, `Variable`...?

Comment: either, but you may also need universe polymorphism.

Comment: @ejgallego: It's a bit difficult to see a connection between `Reset` and defining universe polymorphic functions. Could you give an example of using universe polymorphism to substitute `Reset`?

Answer (score 0):

I've found 2 ways. `Reset Initial` destroys the entire environment (which is usually more than one would want). Another way is to mask universes w/ modules

```
Universe M R. Constraint M < R.
Definition M := Type@{M}. Definition R := Type@{R}.
Check M:R. Fail Check R:M. (*the hierarchy holds*)

(*1. w/ modules:*)
Module i.
Universe M R. Constraint R < M.
Check M:R. Fail Check R:M. (*still holds*)
Definition M := Type@{M}. Definition R := Type@{R}. (*but now..*)
Fail Check M:R. Check R:M.  (*not any more*)
Print Sorted Universes. (*2 Rs and Ms, w/ the old hierarchy masked by the new one*)
End i.

(*outside the module the old hierarchy holds*)
Check M:R. Fail Check R:M.

(*2. w/ Reset Initial:*)
Reset Initial. Fail Check M:R. Fail Check R:M.
Print Sorted Universes. (*the def-d univ-s are gone*)
```